# Show that $f$ is $m$-times differentiable with $f^{(m)}\in L^2(\mathbb T)$ provided $k-m>\frac{1}{2}$.

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis

Assume $f\in L^1(\mathbb T)$ and $\hat f(n)=O(|n|^{-k})$. Show that $f$ is $m$-times differentiable with $f^{(m)}\in L^2(\mathbb T)$ provided $k-m>\frac{1}{2}$.

---

Since $\hat f(n)=O(|n|^{-k})$, we know that $\widehat{f^{(m-1)}}(n)=O(|n|^{m-k-1})$ which implies $f^{(m-1)}$ is continous. Now it suffices to show that $f^{(m-1)}$ is differentiable. What we have now is $f^{(m-1)}(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\widehat{f^{(m-1)}}(n)e^{int} $. If we take the derivative formlly, then we have $ f^{(m)}(t)\sim i\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty n\widehat{f^{(m-1)}}(n)e^{int} $. So we are interested in proving the uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty n\widehat{f^{(m-1)}}(n)e^{int}$ on $\mathbb T$. But I don't have a good idea to use $\widehat{f^{(m-1)}}(n)=O(|n|^{m-k-1})$ with $k-m>\frac 12$. Any suggestion?

Comment: summation by parts?

Comment: @mathworker21 I think I have tried to use summation by parts, but we do not have a monotonic decreasing convergent sequence. Note that $\widehat{f^{(m-1)}}(n)=O(|n|^{m-k-1})$ with $k-m>\frac 12$ and it is possible for this sequence to be non-monotonic.

Comment: idk why ur talking about monotonic stuff. what i mean is: $\sum_{n \le N} g(n)b_n = g(N)(\sum_{n \le N} b_n)-\int_1^N (\sum_{n \le t} b_n)g'(t)dt$.

Comment: @mathworker21 Yes, that's what I mean. So how do you prove this series converges without using the conditions of [Abel's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_test) or [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test)?